# Affix hide top when active

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sticky

I have a navbar and wanted to apply affix, but only to half of that navbar. The whole thing is 1 solid block. I figured that when affix is active I could try to set the top attribute to a negative number and get rid of that upper part of navbar. I just don't know how to do this. Any suggestion is welcomed.

So this is what I tried:

```
<nav id="header-nav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="50">
     <div class="row1"></div>
     <div class="row2"></div>
</nav>
```

The CSS for this is:

```
.row1{
padding-top: 10px;
}

.row2 {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.affix {
    top: -10px;
    width: 100%;
}

#header-nav.affix {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
}
```

But apparently top doesn't seem to change anything at all.

Comment: Hi, you need to post your code so we have a working demo of what you have and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @MichaelCoker added what I have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually works just putting `margin-top: -50px;` in .affix class. The problem was that the G.Chrome decides to use the old CSS than the new one sometimes. I just ran it from **inspect element->network** with "*Disable cache*" checked.

Only this is needed in CSS:

```
.affix {
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: 100%;
}
```